# Level shifting 2.4V to 3.3V

Tags: circuit-design, esp8266, level-shifting, hardware

What design can I follow to make a level shifter? I have used SN75LBC.  Its RE/DE has an output of 2-2.4V and I want it to connect to the receive pin of my ESP. The ESP WROOM-02 operates at 3.3V so I need to shift the level voltage.

What are the options to make the level shifter? Can I use transistors? ICs?

Comment: DE and /RE are inputs. And you have to compare the VOH/VIH specifications, but this is not possible if you keep the part numbers and datasheets a secret.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are various standard buffer (quad, octal) IC that can do this. Depending on how many signals you have, that might be the best solution.

Comment: If you are looking for RS485 interface chip with 3.3v, [MAX3485](https://www.mouser.sg/datasheet/2/609/MAX3483_MAX3491-3128969.pdf) is widely available and operated at 3.3v. No level shifter required.